# Null Pointer exception in getter function

Tags: android, getter-setter

I am developing an application in which I am getting data from server and I am using getter and setter functions to set these.

Here is my code...

```
JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(0);
pojo = new Pojo();
empid = jsonObj1.optString("empid");                
pojo.setId(empid);
```

And I am using getter function as

```
Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
String id = pojo.getId();
```

Here are my setter and getter functions

```
public class Pojo {
    private String empid;

    public void setId(String empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return empid;
    }
}
```

I am getting **Null Pointer Exception** at where I am using getter function.
Am I doing anything wrong? Can anyone please help me.

Comment: it wont work! it looks like you are creating another object and it will obviously give you null pointer exception. try to use same object for which you have set value.

Comment: `pojo.setId(empid);` after setting your `empid` to this object. Are you adding this to any `ArrayList<?>` Or on same line you're trying to get the `ID`

Comment: Unless you use the same object reference there is no way you can get the value set.
JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
                        JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(0);
  pojo = new Pojo();
  empid = jsonObj1.optString("empid");                
  pojo.setId(empid);

Comment: Pri, it does not work like this. Whenever you are doing new Pojo(), it will create new object.

Comment: @Pri Getter function in another class? What does it mean? Post your code thorugh [pastie.org](http://pastie.org)

Comment: I do not really see the null pointer exception here - and you don't share your error log - but @AbdulAleemAkhund is just right. You cannot just create a new object and expect it to carry any meaningful data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are creating an object from `pojo` once, you don't have to create another one to `get` so remove the `Pojo pojo = new Pojo();` and just put :

```
String id=pojo.getId();
```

Your code should be like :

```
JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(0);
pojo = new Pojo();
empid = jsonObj1.optString("empid");                
pojo.setId(empid);
String id = pojo.getId();
```

Then with the **SAME OBJECT** you'll have your id.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to access the getter function in another Activity. If i use this in another Activity I get null value

Comment: Create a class `pojo = new Pojo()` then you can do stuff there

Comment: yes... i have done that.. still getting null value when using getter

Comment: Post your update code. btw if it's null the thing is that "empid" is null make a log as `Log.d("empid ", empid);` to see what happens without the pojo class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90422/discussion-between-pri-and-skizo).

Answer (score 0):

Use the same object to set and get value.

```
JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
  JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(0);
  pojo = new Pojo();
  empid = jsonObj1.optString("empid");                
  pojo.setId(empid);

 String id=pojo.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

it wont work!!  you are creating another object and it will obviously give you null pointer exception. Whenever you are doing new Pojo(), it will create new object. try to use same object for which you have set value.